# Add outline to canvas shape on hover?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So far I have this, which works fine:

```
def OnHover(event):                  
    canvas.itemconfig(c1, outline="#3385ff", width = hw)
def UnHover(event):                  
    canvas.itemconfig(c1, outline="")
canvas.tag_bind(shape, '<Enter>', OnHover)
canvas.tag_bind(shape, '<Leave>', UnHover)
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to use a small amount of code to give multiple shapes this effect.
I currently have this, which is considerably messy and could be tidied and shortened, but I'm a bit stuck.

```
def OnHover1(event):                  
    canvas.itemconfig(c1, outline="#3385ff", width = hw)
def UnHover1(event):                  
    canvas.itemconfig(c1, outline="")
for i in tbh1:
    canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Enter>', OnHover1)
    canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Leave>', UnHover1)
    
def OnHover2(event):                  
    canvas.itemconfig(c4, outline="#3385ff", width = hw)
def UnHover2(event):                  
    canvas.itemconfig(c4, outline="")
for i in tbh2:
    canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Enter>', OnHover2)
    canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Leave>', UnHover2) 

def OnHover3(event):                  
    canvas.itemconfig(c7, outline="#3385ff", width = hw)
def UnHover3(event):                  
    canvas.itemconfig(c7, outline="")
for i in tbh3:
    canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Enter>', OnHover3)
    canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Leave>', UnHover3)
```

Sorry if I havent worded this well.

Comment: just add arguments to the function? like `id_` and `color` so that those can be configured when calling the funciton

Comment: What do you mean by 'multiple shapes'? Your code is already changing outline color and width.

Comment: @Derek sorry I worded that so badly, and to be honest I'm still not sure how to word it. Look at henrys solution as this solved it.

Comment: Has your question been answered yet? If not then do you want to be able to change a canvas `polygon` object's SHAPE when ever you move the mouse into or out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understood what you were asking, but here's what I came up with:

```
def OnHover(item, hw):
    canvas.itemconfig(item, outline="#3385ff", width = hw)
def UnHover(item):
    canvas.itemconfig(item, outline="")

def bindList(l, item, hw):
    for i in l:
        canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Enter>', lambda event: OnHover(item=item, hw=hw))
        canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Leave>', lambda event: UnHover(item=item))
bindList(tbh1, c1, hw)
bindList(tbh2, c4, hw)
bindList(tbh3, c7, hw)
```

There's now a `bindList` function, which goes through the list and tag_binds each item. The OnHover and UnHover functions now take the item you want to change the outline of. I'm not able to test this as I don't know what c1, c4, tbh1, etc. are or what they contain, but this should work.